# R data division from a txt file

Tags: r

I would like to make a division with "8.3" in 10 elements from a txt file. I read the txt file but which way can I make a division of each data? Thanks.

For example: data1--> 155/8.3  195/8.3 .....etc.    data2--> 130/8.3  10/8.3 .....etc.

A sample of my code for reading data:

```
speeddata=read.table("c:\\SpeedData\\Data.txt",header=TRUE)
attach(speeddata)
names(speeddata)
```

Txt Link:
http://www.sendspace.com/file/dka9j1

Comment: What do you mean 8.3? How do you want to divide the data?

Comment: For example: data1--> 155/8.3  195/8.3 .....    data2--> 130/8.3  10/8.3 ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this?

```
dat <- read.table("Data.txt", header = TRUE)

newdat <- dat / 8.3

#         data1      data2
# 1  18.6746988 15.6626506
# 2  23.4939759  1.2048193
# 3   2.5301205  3.1325301
# 4   1.8072289 25.3012048
# 5  22.8915663  1.8072289
# 6   0.2409639 24.6987952
# 7  21.9277108  6.0240964
# 8  13.8554217  6.6265060
# 9  20.4819277  0.1204819
# 10  2.0481928  6.7469880
```

You can save the new data frame with `write.table`:

```
write.table(newdat, "NewData.txt", quote = FALSE, row.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: Yes for this I am looking for but it is possible these values to write in a txt file. I must create a new file in order to have the new values on a txt? Thanks a lot for the help.